# xslt remove string and special character from number in xml

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

During xslt transformation, I have tried to clean string and special from customer number, but it doesnt work. I need to remove c: or s: from the number. Thanks :)

**Xml File 1**

```
<Data>
 <Request>
   <CustNo>c:222</CustNo>
 </Request>
</Data>
```

**Xml File 2**

```
<Data>
 <Request>
   <CustNo>s:333</CustNo>
 </Request>
</Data>
```

**XSLT**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" >
            <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:template match="Request" >
                <TestPayment>
                    <Transactions>
                        <Transaction  custno="{CustNo}" >           
                        </Transaction>
                    </Transactions>
                </TestPayment>
            </xsl:template>
             <xsl:template match="Request/CustNo">
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex=(^c:[a-zA-Z0-9]*$,^s:[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ )"/>
             </xsl:template>
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result of Xml File 1:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TestPayment>
      <Transactions>
        <Transaction custno="222">
        </Transaction>
      </Transactions>
    </TestPayment>
```

**Result of Xml File 2:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TestPayment>
      <Transactions>
        <Transaction custno="333">
        </Transaction>
      </Transactions>
    </TestPayment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try a double-translate function?

```
<Transaction custno="{translate(CustNo, translate(CustNo, '0123456789', ''), '')}" >
```

Comment: This is fixed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0, you could do simply:

```
replace(CustNo, '\D', '')
```

to remove any non-digit characters.

Even in XSLT 1.0, you could use:

```
substring-after(CustNo, ':')
```

to accommodate both your examples.